# What is the convergence of the maclaurin series arcsin(x)?

Tags: calculus

I’m having trouble determining properties of the series arcsin(x), and it’s convergence is one of them, others being radius of convergence, its summation, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The domain is just $[-1,1]$, so there aren't too many possibilities (in the sense that the convergence is probably either $\{0\}$, $(-1,1)$, or $[-1,1]$). I would start by writing down an expression for the $n$-th coefficient in the expansion at the desired point (probably $x=0$), and try the ratio test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that
$$\arcsin x=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx}=\int{(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ dx}$$
Using the binomial expansion series we get
$$\int{(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ dx}=\int{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\prod_{j=1}^{i}{(\frac{1}{2}-j)}\ \frac{(-x^2)^i}{i!}}\ dx}$$
$$=\int{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\prod_{j=1}^{i}{(2j-1)}\ \frac{x^{2i}}{2^ii!}}\ dx}=\int{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(2i)!}{(2^ii!)^2}x^{2i}}\ dx}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\int{\frac{(2i)!}{(2^ii!)^2}x^{2i}\ dx}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(2i)!}{(2^ii!)^2} \frac{x^{2i+1}}{2i+1}}$$
And so above is the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin x$. Because the binomial expansion is valid when $|-x^2|=x^2<1$, and hence $|x|<1$, so the radius of convergence is exactly $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should take into account the fact that this question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508).